# Make select box unique when using jcf modifyer

Tags: javascript

I got this site designed already by front end designers. All select boxes are restyled when the page run in a browser. The problem is I want to show the previously selected value but I dont know how to do that if I cant assign a unique id to the modified select. Here is the modified drop down html:

```
<div unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width: 66px; " class=" select-area select-modify_select  
select-focus ">
 <span class="left"></span>
  <span class="center">B.N.S.</span>
  <a class="select-opener"></a>
</div>

<select name="ach_bank" id="ach_bank" class="modify_select jcf-hidden" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); ">

                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="B.N.S.">B.N.S.</option>                
                    <option value="F.G.B.">F.G.B.</option>                
                    <option value="N.C.B.">N.C.B.</option>                
                    <option value="R.B.C.">R.B.C.</option>                
</select>
```

As you can see the regular select box is hidden and a modified drop down is created. The code that modified the select box is here:

```
// custom select module
jcf.addModule({
name:'select',
selector:'select',
defaultOptions: {
    handleDropPosition: true,
    wrapperClass:'select-area',
    focusClass:'select-focus',
    dropActiveClass:'select-active',
    selectedClass:'item-selected',
    disabledClass:'select-disabled',
    valueSelector:'span.center',
    optGroupClass:'optgroup',
    openerSelector:'a.select-opener',
    selectStructure:'<span class="left"></span><span class="center"></span>
            <a  class="select-opener"></a>',
    selectPrefixClass:'select-',
    dropMaxHeight: 200,
    dropFlippedClass: 'select-options-flipped',
    dropHiddenClass:'options-hidden',
    dropScrollableClass:'options-overflow',
    dropClass:'select-options',
    dropClassPrefix:'drop-',
    dropStructure:'<div class="drop-holder"><div class="drop-list">
            </div></div>',
    dropSelector:'div.drop-list'
},
```

I however do not know how to modify the script to create a unique id for each created select.

I kow that the modification would fall in this line:

```
selectStructure:'<span class="left"></span><span class="center" **id="someid"**></span>
            <a  class="select-opener"></a>',
```

If i place an id in the code, then all the modified select have the same id. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when I received the front-end markup from an outside source. Turns out, it's a simple solution!

In the jQuery, this is currently written:

```
selector:'select',
```

It selects ALL of the 'select' elements and applies the styles to each of them. In order to fix this, add a class name or id in this line, like this:

```
selector:'select.classname',
```

OR

```
selector:'select#idname',
```

Then simply apply the class name or id to the select fields that you want the custom styles applied to.

Comment: do you know where the jcf library originates from? I was given a site design where they based everything on this and no one can tell me where it comes from, docs etc.

Comment: @RichardEdwards Sorry, sure don't. I only encountered this problem when using a plugin for a custom select, Dropkick.js.

Comment: It comes from www.psd2html.com

Comment: I don't even know why would someone use this library. Zero documentation + bad design ... You would be better writing custom style attributes for each field rather than using that garbage...